# How can I set preferred software to opening video files on *buntu?

Tags: ubuntu, video, double-click

Can you please help me out on how to set a software on *buntu to be the only one to automatically open when double clicking in any kind of video file?

PS: I know how to do it normally. I faced a situation sometime ago that I thought was not solved, when trying to find the application I wanted to set up I was not finding it though... well, I tried after asking here and inf fact everything is all working now... The application is on the list and I was able to change it. I forgot this part that was the most relevant to the question...

Comment: What have you researched and attempted? Did you look in the support area for Ubuntu?

Comment: Please decide on one of the *buntus. It’s different in every desktop environment, so there’s no universal way.

Comment: Oh, I see @DanielB but I added some info... and in my case it's all right with a right click => open with => choose the application and then check the option to maintain that application as the default one. But the one I wanted didn't show up as far as I remember, this is what I should've included. I just forgot that part because it happened around weeks ago and now I remembered and "oh, let me ask"... so forgot this part... But I should've tried again before asking... because now it works fine! Sorry guys, know your time is valuable :) Thanks to you both

Comment: So @CharlieRB, you can see the edit I did as well and the comment above. Thanks :) Solved!

Answer (score 1):

#### Change the default application

This changes the default application not just for the selected file, but for all files with the same type.
You can change the default application that is used to open files of a given type. This will allow you to open your preferred application when you double-click to open a file. For example, you might want your favorite music player to open when you double-click an MP3 file.

You can change the default application that is used to open files of a given type. This will allow you to open your preferred application when you double-click to open a file. For example, you might want your favorite music player to open when you double-click an MP3 file.

1. Select a file of the type whose default application you want to change. For example, to change which application is used to open MP3 files, select a .mp3 file.
2. Right-click the file and select *Properties*.
3. Select the *Open With* tab.
4. Select the application you want and click *Set as default*. By default, the file manager only shows applications it knows can handle the file. To look through all the applications on your computer, right-click the file, select *Open With* -> *Other Application* and click *Show Other Applications*.

   If *Other Applications* contains an application you sometimes want to use, but don't want to make the default, select that application and click *Add*. This will add it to *Recommended Applications*. You will then be able to use this application by right-clicking the file and selecting it from the list.

This changes the default application not just for the selected file, but for all files with the same type.

[image: IMG:]